# Router as VPN client; which routes to let attached devices to see resources in the VPN?

Tags: router, routing

I am using an OpenVpn server (ip 192.168.7.141), which gives 10.8.0.x Ips and everything works fine if I use a device to directly connect to it: the device is able to connect to the LAN the server is on (192.168.7.x).

But if I connect a router instead, none of the connected devices is able to reach the remote LAN. I think I am missing a static route or two, but I don't know which ones. The router is connected at 192.168.0.1 and its clients have 192.168.0.x ips.

No restriction is needed, connected device should work like if they were on the remote 192.168.7.x LAN (short of receiving broadcasts from the remote LAN; avahi and similar are not needed to work).

I have full control of iptables and much more on my router (it is an Asus-WRT device, merlin build), but maybe I can do this through the web interface as well. Both approaches are fine to me.

Thanks for your help, I am not expert in this kind of networking.

Comment: Do you only need to _reach_ devices on the remote LAN, or do you also want to see them in Windows' _network discovery_ thing?

Comment: The easiest way is for you to do source  NAT on the client OpenVPN router. The more correct way is to use route commands on the client and an appropriate iroute directive on the server for the clients specific routes.

Comment: @grawity I just want to reach them; if it il will also work on Windows Descovery/Avahi/Whatever it's a plus but not necessary.

Comment: @davidgo an example would be great, like I said I am no expert in this